# How to change value of Annotation without server restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websphere-portal

I have below code:

```
@Value("${XXX.Run.Flag}") 
private String xxxABC;
```

I am reading the value of XXX.Run.Flag from my config.properties file.

Now whenever i make change in the value of this key in my config files, it do not get reflected until and unless i restart the server. I am aware that Annotations gets initialised during the application start up.

I do not want to restart the server if i make any change in the annotation key value. Can someone suggest me how to do this.

I am using Portlet Spring MVC 3.0.

Comment: I don't know websphere specifically, but most other application servers allow you to undeploy/redeploy your application. You do still need to restart *your* code, but not the entirety of Websphere.

Comment: Have you looked at http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/ ?

Comment: @dcsohl: Thanks but i cannot undeploy/deploy the application also as it is not recommended for Production Environment

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.wuenschenswert.net/wunschdenken/archives/127

Comment: Link updated. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use `net.unicon.springframework.addons.properties.ReloadablePropertiesFactoryBean` as described [here](https://github.com/Unicon/springframework-addons/wiki/Auto-reloading-properties-files)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Spring cloud config server](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) , it does offer a lot including what you are asking for

`@RefreshScope` for Spring `@Beans` that want to be re-initialized when configuration changes,